# SAS reporting totals

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks somewhat similar to the example below:

ID  Year    College Dept    Deg Status

12  2014    Engineering CS  MS  Applied

12  2014    Engineering CS  MS  Admitted

12  2014    Engineering CS  MS  Enrolled

88  2013    Engineering ME  PHD Applied

88  2013    Engineering ME  PHD Admitted

44  2014    Engineering CE  MS  Applied

I am trying to produce a report that's more like this:

Year    Applied Admitted    Enrolled

2013    X       Y       Z

2014    X       Y       Z

I know how to filter the datasets for the College/Dept/Deg, but how can I use SAS to essentially make fields within a column headers?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a dataset or output in results window? If output look at proc freq/tabulate/report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming X, Y, and Z are supposed to be counts, `proc sql` works great for this sort of thing. Below, four columns are defined in the `select` clause. The first column is `year`. The second column, `sum(status='applied')`, counts the number of rows where the expression `status='applied'` is true, and so on for the next two columns.

```
proc sql;
select year,
       sum(status='Applied') as applied,
       sum(status='Admitted') as admitted,
       sum(status='Enrolled') as enrolled
from yourdata
group by year
;
quit;
```

You could also use `proc report`, and easily generate the columns dynamically (one column for each value found in `status`). `year` and `group` are both define as `group` variables. `Across` puts the statuses in columns rather than creating a row for each status:

```
proc report data=yourdata;
  columns year status;
  define year / group;
  define status / group across;
run;
```

You can get something similar to this with `proc freq` by just requesting a twoway frequency table with `year*status`. Use the `norow`, `nocol`, `nopercent` options to suppress all the junk that `proc freq normally spits out:

```
proc freq data=yourdata;
  tables year*status / norow nocol nopercent;
run;
```

Or you could use `proc tabulate`. Define `year` and `status` as `class` variables, and the following `table` statement will get you the counts you want:

```
proc tabulate data=yourdata;
  class year status;
  table year, status*n;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ended up doing a blend of almost everything you mentioned.   I got the counts with PROC SQL, but used it differently so I had to also use PROC TRANSPOSE, then used PROC REPORT for formatting the output.  Thanks again.